# Making date change functional, instead of manually change date in the code with pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Motivation: the code I have multiple spots where target date located. I've been manually change all of the target date to run the code. But you know, it would be nice if I can make this automated.

My trial
1. success: I was able to make target date functional via using timedelta.
2. error: however, when I insert it in the code, data seems not correct. For the example below, I set target date, '2019-03-29', but the data print out starting '2019-01-01'

Any insight will be very appreciable.

[image]

[image]

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#data import
headers = ['ticker','per','date','time','open','high','low','close','vol']
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\x230\\Downloads\\NQ_190101_190531.csv", sep = ';', names=headers, skiprows=[0])
df['date_time'] = df['date'].map(str) + ' ' + df['time'].map(str)               #combine date and time data
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('date_time',inplace=True)                                          #set time back as index

date_start = '2019-03-28'
date_target = (datetime.strptime(date_start, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#selecting data range
df = df.loc[print(date_target,'01:01:00'):print(date_target,'22:59:00')]
df.head()
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Here is an example: `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2019-01-01 1:00', '2019-02-01 1:00', freq='5H')); df = df.set_index(0); df.loc['2019-01-01 5:00': '2019-01-01 16:00']`

Comment: @ Chris, Thank you for your reply. I may not be clear about my question. What I am looking for is making 'date information' function. I have a long code where I need to type in 'date information' repeatedly, which I am trying to avoid.  For your example code, I am looking for making something like this df.loc['function 5:00': 'function 16:00']. I tried this way, df = df.loc[print(date_target,'01:01:00'):print(date_target,'22:59:00')], but didn't work.

Comment: Can you just append your strings? `df.loc[date_target+' 05:00:00': date_target+' 16:00:00']` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: it works! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution found. As Chris mentioned, appending the strings fix the issue. See below. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you append the final code in text format, rather than as an image?  It saves editing time if we want to reuse your code.  Thank you !!